# How to mock a vector of an arbitrary size?

Tags: c++, vector, mocking, googletest

I've defined a class that accepts a `vector` as a constructor input parameter and provides a method that uses `vector`'s `size()` function:

```
class Foo {
  vector<int> storedVector;

  public:
    explicit Foo(vector<int>);
    bool isSizeGreaterThanInt();
}

Foo::Foo(vector<int> inputVector) : storedVector(std::move(inputVector)) {  }

bool Foo::isSizeGreaterThanInt()
{
  if (storedVector.size() > INT32_MAX) { return true; }

  return false;
}
```

Now I would like to test the `isSizeGreaterThanInt()` method of this class. As part of that test I want to also validate that the `size()` call inside of the implementation returns the `size()` of the vector passed into the constructor and not some other vector/some other size.

I'm using `gtest` and `gmock` as my testing and mocking framework respectively.

All my attempts to create a mock of `vector<int>` which mocks the `size()` function to return a specific value seem to fail, my latest version of the mock is as follows:

```
template <typename VectorValueType>
class MockVector : public std::vector<VectorValueType> {
  public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0_T(size, size_t());
};

TEST(Test,TestCase)
{
  size_t fakeSize = static_cast<size_t>(INT32_MAX) + 1;
  MockVector<int> mockVector;
  EXPECT_CALL(mockVector, size()).WillRepeatedly(testing::Return(fakeSize));

  size_t testSize = mockVector.size(); // here the value is correct

  Foo foo (mockVector);

  // if I debug here and check the size of the vector now stored in foo - it's 0.

  ASSERT_EQ(true, foo.isSizeGreaterThanInt());
}
```

I had concerns about `std::move` and move behavior so I tried passing `inputVector` by reference, tried passing pointers, tried storing `vector<int>& storedVector` instead of having a value member... nothing worked.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? What am I doing wrong?

***Update***

One of the commenters suggested it happens due to splicing of the `MockVector` type into `vector<int>`, and when it's spliced the mocked methods are no longer called... but still, how should I go about mocking the vector? There is no interface for `vector<>` in C++ STL, so I can't make that a parameter to the constructor...

***Update 2***

As suggested in one of the answers, yes, I can add a `getSize()` to `Foo` and mock that... But it changes `Foo`'s contract and I'd prefer not to do that. Furthermore, if I was willing to do that, I still would need to mock my `vector` to test the `getSize()` behavior to ensure that `getSize()` truly returns the `size()` of the vector and not some other value. Basically, doing that is just moving the same problem to a different place.

***Update 3***

Yes, theoretically I can create a vector in my test, just pass it in and not mock it. The issue here is that to test the specific behavior described above I'll need to create a `vector` with (`INT32_MAX + 1`) elements in it, which is prohibitively expensive (resources/time/memory) for the test.

Comment: I don't see a `Foo::size` method anywhere in your definition. What exactly is `foo.size()` in your calling code?

Comment: @NathanPierson Sorry, adjusted the example to better reflect what I'm doing

Comment: Looks like you're experiencing object slicing. `Foo` has a `std::vector<int>` as a value member, so even if you pass it a `MockVector` in the constructor, `storedVector` will be sliced down to the base class and subsequent calls will ignore the mocked method the derived class uses.

Comment: @NathanPierson I understand that. So, what would be a way for me to mock a vector? Or do I need to abstract the `size()` method as a method on `Foo` and mock that? It works but I don't want to change my class signature. There's no "common" vector interface in C++ STL

Comment: `Foo::Foo` takes the vector by value, i.e. before the value is passed to teh constructor, the copy constructor of `std::vector<int>` is invoked which may or may not use the `size()` function. It doesn't help that the `size` function is non-virtual.

Comment: @fabian I'm using `std::move` in the constructor call so no, this is not happening.

Comment: Is there some kind of ellision mechanism I'm overlooking in play here: `Foo foo (mockVector);`? My understanding is that since the parameter type of the constructor is `std::vector<int>` this creates a copy of the vector which is then available for the call of the constructor and it's this copy that gets moved. `mockVector` itself cannot be used as an rvalue reference...

Comment: @fabian I think @NathanPierson is correct about slicing - my mocked object gets sliced into `std::vector<int>` and no longer proxies calls to mock functions. But it doesn't explain what I should do... Ideally the `Foo` constructor should accept some class that is an interface for `std::vector<>` and than I can mock that instead and there will be no splicing but `std::vector<>` does not have a base class/interface.

Comment: `INT32_MAX` is a signed int value, `INT32_MAX + 1` leads to signed int value overflow, undefined behavior.

Comment: @S.M. No. Please read the question. `fakeSize` is defined as `size_t`, which in most cases (including the system/architecture I'm running this on) happens to be `unsigned long long`. And that's not even what the question is about.

Comment: You missed some knowledge of implicit type casts in C++. The result of `INT32_MAX + 1` is cast to `size_t`, but the type of the expression `INT32_MAX + 1` is `int` as the sum of two ints.

Comment: @S.M. Yes, you are right about that. I have a static cast in my actual code, added it here... but it's still in no way relevant to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mock methods of `std::vector`, because mocking system in GoogleTest is based on polymorphism and `std::vector` is not prepared for use in polymorphism - none of its methods are `virtual`. Since `size()` method is not `virtual`, the mock implementation will never be called and GoogleMock cannot register that call or execute actions.

The only way to test that would be to pass the vector of size `INT32_MAX` to the tested class (perhaps this test should be disabled by default and only enabled in CI envireonment) or to create a wrapper for `std::vector` which will have `virtual` methods in its interface.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to templatize the method, and instead of requiring a vector create a custom trait to describe a vector?

Comment: @PhilP. That could be an option as well. GoogleMock documentation has a section on using templates to inject mocks: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods